# Android,SAX parser Problem while reading Html Tags

Tags: android, android-emulator

**i want to parse this text with Sax Parser,the problem is due to Html tags in content tag string buffer is not going to read Html tags can any one suggest me how to do it with Sax Parser,or refer me any of the links that parse Html data with SAX**

[image: Text to parse With SAX]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML file is not XML conformant.

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit the text you provided, simply use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

```
<content><![CDATA[Your stuff here with all the <em>HTML</em> tags you can think of.]]></content>
```

Then SAX Parser's `toString()` will return a string like this: `Your stuff here with all the <em>HTML</em> tags you can think of.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to put CDATA in data (Parameter DATA: Actual Data; TAG: Name of XML tag where CDATA needs to be put.)

```
 public static final String putCDATA(String data, String tag) {
    if(data == null || data.length() <= 0 || tag == null || tag.length() <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    String newData = "";

    while(true) {
        int firstIndex = data.indexOf("<" + tag + ">");
        firstIndex = firstIndex + new String("<" + tag + ">").length() - 1;

        int lastIndex = data.indexOf("</" + tag + ">");

        if(firstIndex == -1 || lastIndex == -1) {
            break;
        }

        String tagValue = data.substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex);
        tagValue = "<![CDATA[" + tagValue + "]]>";

        newData += data.substring(0,firstIndex + 1);
        newData += tagValue;
        newData += data.substring(lastIndex, lastIndex + new String("<" + tag + ">").length() + 1);

        data = data.substring(lastIndex + new String("<" + tag + ">").length() + 1, data.length());
    }

    newData += data;

    System.out.print("FORMATED: " + "\n" + newData);
    return newData;
}
```